# Android приложение, не могу получить данные из БД

Tags: java, android, sqlite

У меня есть активность, где пользователю предлагается выбрать категорию напитков, далее через ListView он попадает с подробным описанием напитка. Проблема в том что у меня активность не может получить записи из БД

Активность с категориями напитков

```
public class DrinkCategoryActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
private SQLiteDatabase db;
private Cursor cursor;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_drink_category);

    ListView listDrinks = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_drinks);
    SQLiteOpenHelper starbuzzDatabaseHelper = new StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(this);
    try {
        db = starbuzzDatabaseHelper.getReadableDatabase();
        cursor = db.query("DRINK",
                new String[]{"_id", "NAME"},
                null, null, null, null, null);

        SimpleCursorAdapter listAdapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                cursor,
                new String[]{"NAME"},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0);
        listDrinks.setAdapter(listAdapter);
    }
    catch(SQLiteException e){
        Toast toast = Toast.makeText(this, "Database unavailable", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
        toast.show();
    }


    AdapterView.OnItemClickListener itemClickListener = new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> listDrinks, View itemView, int position, long id) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DrinkCategoryActivity.this, DrinkActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra(DrinkActivity.EXTRA_DRINKID, (int) id);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    };
    listDrinks.setOnItemClickListener(itemClickListener);
}

@Override
public void onDestroy(){
    super.onDestroy();
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
}
```

}

БД SQLite

```
public class StarbuzzDatabaseHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static final String DB_NAME = "starbuzz";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 2;

    StarbuzzDatabaseHelper(Context context) {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, 0, DB_VERSION);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        updateMyDatabase(db, oldVersion, newVersion);
    }
    private static void insertDrink(SQLiteDatabase db, String name, String description, int resourceId){
        ContentValues drinkValues = new ContentValues();
        drinkValues.put("NAME", name);
        drinkValues.put("DESCRIPTION", description);
        drinkValues.put("IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID", resourceId);
        db.insert("DRINK", null, drinkValues);
    }
    private void updateMyDatabase(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        if (oldVersion < 1) {
            db.execSQL("CREATE TABLE DRINK (_id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "
                    + "NAME TEXT, "
                    + "DESCRIPTION TEXT, "
                    + "IMAGE_RESOURCE_ID INTEGER);");
            insertDrink(db, "Latte", "Espresso and steamed milk", R.drawable.latte);
            insertDrink(db, "Cappuccino", "Espresso, hot milk and steamed-milk foam",
                    R.drawable.cappuccino);
            insertDrink(db, "Filter", "Our best drip coffee", R.drawable.filter);
        }
        if (oldVersion < 2) {
            db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE DRINK ADD COLUMN FAVORITE NUMERIC;");
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А что конкретно вы подразумеваете под "не может получить записи"? Неверный\пустой запрос, ошибки? Добавьте подробности.

Comment: @EugeneKrivenja Решил проблему, у меня при запуске приложения изначально создалась пустая БД и не обновляла записи когда я вносил какие-то данные